# Android - EditText keyboard type programmatically

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I try to set the keyboard type of an edit text.

When I use below code, it changes the font of the edit text's hint.

```
setInputType(TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
```

So, I try another solution.

```
setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
```

I create an edit text. My password is shown on top of the keyboard.(looks like auto suggestion).

How can I set the keyboard type for password without changing the font of the text?

Answer (score 4):

for Font issue you can try this :

```
    editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
    editText.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Typeface.DEFAULT is not enough. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Solution is here:

```
typeface = edittext.getTypeface(); 
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
editText.setTypeface(typeface);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// this work for me, donot set android:inputType="textPassword" in your xml file and instead, set it in java
     <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    editText.setTransformationMethod(new PasswordTransformationMethod());
```